# WordPress feature images covered with light white color. How should I remove it?

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-theming

```
.wp-block-post-featured-image .wp-block-post-featured-image__overlay.has-background-dim-50 {
    opacity: .5;
}
```

```
.wp-block-post-featured-image .wp-block-post-featured-image__overlay.has-background-dim {
    position: absolute;
    inset: 0;
    background-color: #000;
}
```

```
.has-contrast-background-color {
    background-color: var(--wp--preset--color--contrast) !important;
}
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4k6qV.png)

Remove the color from server side, I know it can be removed in the console, but it will appear again after I reload the page.

Answer (score 0):

Replace your CSS :

```
.wp-block-post-featured-image .wp-block-post-featured-image__overlay.has-background-dim {
    position: absolute;
    inset: 0;
    background-color: #000;
}
```

with this CSS :

```
.wp-block-post-featured-image .wp-block-post-featured-image__overlay.has-background-dim.has-contrast-background-color {
    position: absolute;
    inset: 0;
    background-color: #000 !important;
}
```